# ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID trying to connect to docker container

Tags: docker, scrapy, docker-toolbox

[image]

I'm getting started with docker using  docker-toolbox on win 10 home. I'm experimenting with scrapy splash project (https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash). I've installed the toolbox on a flash drive (e:)

If I understand correctly I have installed docker using the docker toolbox. When I click on the docker quickstart terminal, I get the screenshot.

I ran:

```
$ docker-machine start
```

but when I :

```
$ docker run -it scrapinghub/splash
2019-05-25 22:33:53+0000 [-] Log opened.
2019-05-25 22:33:53.053632 [-] Splash version: 3.3.1
2019-05-25 22:33:53.054895 [-] Qt 5.9.1, PyQt 5.9.2, WebKit 602.1, sip 4.19.4, Twisted 18.9.0, Lua 5.2
2019-05-25 22:33:53.055695 [-] Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2019-05-25 22:33:53.056773 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
2019-05-25 22:33:53.057319 [-] Can't bump open files limit
2019-05-25 22:33:53.165435 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':1788299128', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
2019-05-25 22:33:53.257636 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, proxy profiles path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
2019-05-25 22:33:53.258827 [-] memory cache: enabled, private mode: enabled, js cross-domain access: disabled
2019-05-25 22:33:53.422507 [-] verbosity=1, slots=20, argument_cache_max_entries=500, max-timeout=90.0
2019-05-25 22:33:53.424799 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
2019-05-25 22:33:53.426021 [-] Site starting on 8050
2019-05-25 22:33:53.426778 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7efcd8d8dcc0>
2019-05-25 22:33:53.427649 [-] Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050
```

I tried to open the browser at

```
http://0.0.0.0:8050
```

But get the error in the title. What am I doing wrong?

edit:

I had to remove prior container by :

```
docker container ls
docker rm -f <container-name>
```

Then it worked at :

http://192.168.99.100:8050/

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IP address that means "everywhere"; you shouldn't try to make outbound connections to it.  You actually need the IP address from your Docker Toolbox screenshot (192.168.99.100).

Comment: I tried http://192.168.99.100:850/ - same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the publishing part.

```
docker run -it -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```

Comment: $ docker run -it -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
E:\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint vigilant_hermann (964e7afd23381742fcd7b481e7f2021f5956fd5b8f443f37adf98412d781416d): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8050 failed: port is already allocated.